# What does a percentage mean in `word-spacing` property?

Tags: css

[According to MDN, the `word-spacing` property can take a percentage value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing), which "specifies extra spacing as a percentage of the affected character’s advance width." However, some things contradict this:

- The demo on that page appears to show that `word-spacing: 120%;` is an error.
- When I apply a percentage `word-spacing` in Chrome, I get the error "Invalid property value".
- [The CSSWG doc](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#propdef-word-spacing) says "Percentages: N/A".

Is MDN wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the MDN is not up to date because percetange value is (or was) a valid value proposed in the  New Specification (CSS Text Level 3) but in [the actual Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/) you can read:

> The following features are at-risk, and may be dropped during the CR period:
>
> ...
>
> - the percentage values of word-spacing
>
> “At-risk” is a W3C Process term-of-art, and does not necessarily imply that the feature is in danger of being dropped or delayed. It means that the WG believes the feature may have difficulty being interoperably implemented in a timely manner, and marking it as such allows the WG to drop the feature if necessary when transitioning to the Proposed Rec stage, without having to publish a new Candidate Rec without the feature first.

Maybe the percentage value will be dropped.

By the way, the percentage value works fine on Firefox and MDN is up to date saying this:

[image]